# Vectorized way to shuffle characters of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am interested in shuffle all characters of the strings in a list, and to do this on a single string, there are two possibilities:

```
''.join(random.sample(string, k=len(string)))
```

OR

```
string_utils.shuffle(string)
```

However, I need to shuffle around 10^8 strings I have in a list, and doing something like a list comprehension takes forever.

Is there a vectorized or more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not. You might be able to speed things up slightly if your strings are simple & uniform. Are they all the same length? Do you need to handle full Unicode, or can you restrict them to plain ASCII, or at least an 8 bit char set? Do they just need to _look_ shuffled, or do the characters need to be shuffled by a proper unbiased process?

Comment: @PM2Ring They are all capital letters in the English alphabet and needs to be shuffled by a proper unbiased process. Not same length :(

Comment: Shuffling the strings is independent. One approach might be to chunk the list and use `multiprocessing`, sending each `Process` its own chunk to shuffle. Then you can re-combine the list at the end.

Comment: I just ran some quick tests. If you store you letters in bytearrays, you can shuffle them in-place, and that runs in about half the time as your `''.join(random.sample(string, k=len(string)))`. But then you have the overhead of encoding & decoding the strings in & out of the bytearrays, which kills the time difference. But if you need to shuffle each string many times, and only need to encode & decode once on each string, then that might be ok.

Comment: How is the distribution of string lengths? More like 10 or 20 different lengths or thousands of different lengths?

Comment: You mentioned vectorizing, which usually implies Numpy. Now Numpy _can_ handle strings, but it's not designed to do fast stuff with them. You could convert the chars to 8 bit ints (similar to using bytearrays), but because the strings aren't of uniform length you won't get much benefit from Numpy, since you can't put your strings into a proper arrays, i.e., an array with each row having the same length. However, their _might_ be some package that does what you want that I'm simply ignorant of. ;)

Comment: Good question, Michael Butscher. If the strings are approximately of uniform length we could break them up into groups of exactly uniform length. Or pad them with a dummy char to make them uniform, and discard the dummies after shuffling.

Comment: @PM2Ring They are mostly between 8 and 24 characters in length.

Comment: As a starting point I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/butscher/d8720666fa91861e57dffd00c761822b) to show how vectorized shuffling for fixed length byte sequences can be done.